# Is there a regular expression for MMSI(Maritime Mobile Service Identity)

Tags: regex

Is there a regular expression for MMSI ([Maritime Mobile Service Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_Mobile_Service_Identity))?

> MIDxxxxxx
>   MIDxxx000
>   0MIDxxxxx
>   00MIDxxxx

Where x is a digit

I tried the following regex:

```
^(0*MID(\d{4,6}))$
```

but it also accepts longer than 9 digits,
how can I limit the total phrase length?

Comment: why don't you build on your own?

Comment: There are online libraries of regex patterns that you could search, but recommending off-site resources is not on-topic.  You could make your own, but you aren't clear about which part of doing so you are having trouble with.

Comment: This is a good question but some want to know what you already tried. This regex should help you MID\d{6}|MID\d{3}000|0MID\d{5}|00MID\d{4}

Comment: @buckley, I tried this: ^(0*MID(\d{4,6}))$ but I can't limit the string length to 9, can you assist?

Comment: This works: `^(MID\d{3}(000|\d{3}))|0MID\d{5}|00MID\d{4}$`.  You can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/hH0pV1/1

Comment: This only accepts string of length 9 ^(MID\d{6}|MID\d{3}000|0MID\d{5}|00MID\d{4})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply distinguish between the 3 cases :

```
^(MID\d{6}|0MID\d{5}|00MID\{4})$
```

If you want to keep your expression you can add a positive look-ahead over it :

```
^(?=.{9})0*MID(\d{4,6})$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a complete regular expression for MMSI that complies with the most recent [Coast Guard guidelines](https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?pageName=mtMmsi), I wrote this one:

```
^((((2(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))|([3-6][0-9]{2})|(7([0-6][0-9]|7[0-5])))[0-9]{6})|((0|8)((2(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))|([3-6][0-9]{2})|(7([0-6][0-9]|7[0-5])))[0-9]{5})|((00|99|98)((2(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))|([3-6][0-9]{2})|(7([0-6][0-9]|7[0-5])))[0-9]{4})|(111((2(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))|([3-6][0-9]{2})|(7([0-6][0-9]|7[0-5])))[0-9]{3})|((970|972|974)[0-9]{6}))$
```

or play with it over [here](https://regex101.com/r/KsWYXu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This one works pretty well:

```
^(MID\d{6}|0MID\d{5}|00MID\d{4})$
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC2zU3/1)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Matches the suggested patterns and makes sure its a total length is 9

```
^(MID\d{6}|MID\d{3}000|0MID\d{5}|00MID\d{4})$
```

Comment: `MID\d{3}000` is redundant : all it matches is already matched by `MID\d{6}`